# Use stepper as increaser/decreaser in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uistepper

How can I use `UIStepper` as simple increaser/decreaser?

The only way I've found is to set the value of the `UIStepper` to 1 each time I detect an action and compare the value to 1 when I catch an action:

```
    @IBAction func onStepperValueChangedAction(sender: UIStepper) {
        if sender.value > 1 {
            increaseValue()
        } else {
            decreaseValue()
        }

        sender.value = 1
    }
```

Don't forget to set the default value of the `UIStepper` to 1.

Comment: Are you answering your own question? Or is there a question somewhere in there?

Comment: I would like to know if there's a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
@IBAction func StepperPressed(_ sender: UIStepper) {

    Label.text = Int(sender.value).description

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@IBOutlet weak var splitNumberLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func stepperValueChanged(_ sender: UIStepper) {
    splitNumberLabel.text = String(sender.value)
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var previousValue = 0
     @IBAction func onStepperValueChangedAction(sender: UIStepper) {

            if sender.value > previousValue {
                increaseValue()
            } else {
                decreaseValue()
            }
            previousValue = sender.value
        }
```

Comment: This will not work if I reach the maximum value. Example: If the maximum value of the stepper is 10, the value is 8 and I use the increase button 3 times, only the 2 first actions will be taken into consideration. The third one will be interpreted as a decrease.

Comment: if sender.value >= sender.maximumValue    return

Comment: Still, the 3rd try will not work. It's better because it will not be interpreted as a decrease but in this case it will not be interpreted at all. I think it's better to reset the stepper value each time like I did.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, if it suits your need

```
    if sender.value >  prevCnt {

        increasedValue()
        sender.maximumValue = sender.maximumValue + 1
    }
    else if prevCnt >= 1 {

        decreasedValue()
        sender.maximumValue = sender.maximumValue - 1
    }
```